# Dependency Management Javascript + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies

In my current AngularJS project I am trying to improve my structure a bit.
I know, there are better approaches but I want my project to look like this:

```
controllers/FirstCtrl.js
controllers/SecondCtrl.js
controllers/ThirdCtrl.js
app.js
```

In this case, everytime I add a new Controller I would have to insert it with a script tag in the `index.html` file. I want to avoid this.

What are good approaches to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: bundling & minification. uglify-js

Comment: You could use an automation tool, e.g. [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and its plugins. May be use [grunt-file-blocks](https://github.com/rrharvey/grunt-file-blocks) to auto insert script tags like you want and then use [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) to do the bundling & minification like HarishR mentioned.